# My Samsung Galaxy Note 8 Doesn't Show an "Allow USB Debugging?" Prompt. Is there a fix?

Tags: settings, usb-debugging, data-transfer, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-note-8

Around this morning, I had the idea to transfer all my whatsapp chats(from android to ios)

Not so ***complicated***, right?

Well, I was in for a rude awakening. Not only did I spend literally 7 hours trying to fix it... I couldn't fix it!

That's basically why I'm reaching out to you. My last hope. My knight in shining armor.

Here are the more technical details:

- Before you say it, and I know you will, I'll tell you - I restarted my phone about 10 million times
- I've enabled and disabled usb debugging around 10 million times minus 1.
- I haven't played with adb so I don't screw with my android system. However if that's necessary, I'll do what must be done.
- I'm specifically using my own samsung galaxy note 8 since I previously tried on another phone(LG v20) and it didn't work either.

So, I must ask you, are you up to this challenge? Can you fix what seems unfixable?

P.s. Here's a preview of what should be showing up on my own android device but is not:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I tried using these articles to solve the issue, but to not avail.
1. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101933/galaxy-s4-does-not-show-authorize-usb-debugging-dialog-box

2. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144507/cant-authorise-android-device-in-usb-debugging-mode

Comment: It's not yet mentioned, but the first thing to check is if the USB cable you're using is a data cable, not only a charging cable, i.e. that the device is detected by the computer first and you can browse the content of the smartphone's external storage from the PC. Also, you haven't mentioned the OS of the computer, but assuming it's Windows, then you probably need to [install OEM USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info about the data cable, appreciate it. I actually figured out the cause of the issue: It seems like the profile of the computer(perhaps the RSA key fingerprint) was automatically recognized by the android device and so it didn't ask for any permissions. From there, I'm still kind of trying to understand it. But basically, as soon as I reset(factory reset) my computer, it started prompting me for authorization again. I'm sure the factory reset was on the extreme end of options, but it worked in the end.

Comment: Hello. I appreciate that you found the answer yourself, but please note that this is a Q&A site so we keep questions as questions strictly. Consider posting your solution as an answer in the space provided above the bottom of this page. As for others who visit this question in the future and finds the absence of a solution, visit [this edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/214289/2) from OP.

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option called "Revoke USB Authorization" within the Developer options. Click it and it'll revoke the auth key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the profile of the computer(perhaps the RSA key fingerprint) was automatically recognized by the android device and so it didn't ask for any permissions. From there, I'm still kind of trying to understand it. But basically, as soon as I reset(factory reset) my computer, it started prompting me for authorization again. I'm sure the factory reset was on the extreme end of options, but it worked in the end.